# Difficulty reading .csv file

Tags: c, excel, csv

I am trying to read in a .csv file (output from Excel) in C.  I assumed the file would only be text values, but I have found 3 characters at the beginning of the file.  They are (unsigned char): 239, 187, 191.

Since I am not expecting these values, my reader gets confused and causes problems. But I have not been able to find documentation.  I saved the file as a UTF-8 .csv file from Excel.

Comment: It is a BOM marker. Read the first three bytes and discard them.

Comment: OK, figured it out. Looks like if one saves as UTF-8 .csv that adds the characters (probably header stuff).  If you save as plain .csv, the characters are not present.

Comment: Not exactly doucmentation, but Wikipedia here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The UTF-8 representation of the BOM (byte order mark) is the (hexadecimal) byte sequence 0xEF,0xBB,0xBF. These may be displayed as the characters ï»¿.

In decimal, these values are 239, 187, and 191 as shown above.